# MVVM Light WPF Messenger

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I want to display a messagebox with MVVM Light in WPF. What am I doing wrong?

I have a View (UserControl):

```
    public partial class IetsAnders : UserControl
{
    public IetsAnders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, message =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dit kan ook een custom window worden door een message class te maken en daar mee door te sturen. Te doen voor errors");
            });
    }
}
```

And I have the viewmodel which sends the "request":

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("Test"));
```

But it doesn't trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
    {
        switch (message.Notification)
        {
            case "Test":
                 MessageBox.Show("Dit kan ook een custom window worden door een message class te maken en daar mee door te sturen. Te doen voor errors");           
                break;
        } 
    });
```

Comment: you forget to close the register with );

Thanks but it didnt work :(

Comment: are sure the UserControl is created before the message is sent !

Comment: yeah, just forgot to put in the binding..Sigh...sometimes you just look over it all.. Thanks